# GDM will not start on boot, unable to login into graphical interface

Tags: linux, rhel, selinux, gdm

I am running RHEL 5.8 .

SELinux is enabled but in permissive mode. Here are some snippets from /var/log/messages on boot.

```
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613500.551:6): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=3519 comm="rhgb" name="fontconfig" dev=dm-2 ino=13991937 scontext=system_u:system_r:rhgb_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613500.552:7): avc:  denied  { add_name } for  pid=3519 comm="rhgb" name="beeeeb3dfe132a8a0633a017c99ce0c0-x86-64.cache-2.TMP-U6wBKS" scontext=system_u:system_r:rhgb_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613500.552:8): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=3519 comm="rhgb" name="beeeeb3dfe132a8a0633a017c99ce0c0-x86-64.cache-2.TMP-U6wBKS" scontext=system_u:system_r:rhgb_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613500.556:9): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=3519 comm="rhgb" path="/var/cache/fontconfig/beeeeb3dfe132a8a0633a017c99ce0c0-x86-64.cache-2.TMP-U6wBKS" dev=dm-2 ino=13991947 scontext=system_u:system_r:rhgb_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613500.560:10): avc:  denied  { link } for  pid=3519 comm="rhgb" name="beeeeb3dfe132a8a0633a017c99ce0c0-x86-64.cache-2.TMP-U6wBKS" dev=dm-2 ino=13991947 scontext=system_u:system_r:rhgb_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613500.560:11): avc:  denied  { remove_name } for  pid=3519 comm="rhgb" name="beeeeb3dfe132a8a0633a017c99ce0c0-x86-64.cache-2.TMP-U6wBKS" dev=dm-2 ino=13991947 scontext=system_u:system_r:rhgb_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613500.560:12): avc:  denied  { unlink } for  pid=3519 comm="rhgb" name="beeeeb3dfe132a8a0633a017c99ce0c0-x86-64.cache-2.TMP-U6wBKS" dev=dm-2 ino=13991947 scontext=system_u:system_r:rhgb_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613500.560:13): avc:  denied  { rename } for  pid=3519 comm="rhgb" name="beeeeb3dfe132a8a0633a017c99ce0c0-x86-64.cache-2.NEW" dev=dm-2 ino=13991949 scontext=system_u:system_r:rhgb_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613501.633:14): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=3569 comm="pam_console_app" capability=1 scontext=system_u:system_r:pam_console_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:pam_console_t:s0 tclass=capability
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613503.649:17): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=3635 comm="microcode_ctl" capability=1 scontext=system_u:system_r:cpucontrol_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:cpucontrol_t:s0 tclass=capability
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613521.042:24): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=4911 comm="auditd" capability=1 scontext=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 tclass=capability
kernel: type=1400 audit(1360613521.065:25): avc:  denied  { dac_override } for  pid=4911 comm="auditd" capability=1 scontext=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 tclass=capability
setroubleshoot: [server.ERROR] cannot start systen DBus service: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
kernel: gdm-binary[5394]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fff51edc0d0 error 4
restorecond: Will not restore a file with more than one hard link (/etc/resolv.conf) Invalid argument 
kernel: gdm-binary[5658]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fff5398b9b0 error 4
kernel: gdm-binary[5679]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fff4652f6f0 error 4
kernel: gdm-binary[5700]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fff945e9990 error 4
kernel: gdm-binary[5721]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fffa91ba550 error 4
kernel: gdm-binary[5743]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fffaf12f6e0 error 4
kernel: gdm-binary[5763]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fffb715e800 error 4
restorecond: Will not restore a file with more than one hard link (/etc/resolv.conf) No such file or directory 
kernel: gdm-binary[5788]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fff46b61c10 error 4
kernel: gdm-binary[5809]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fffa5400820 error 4
restorecond: Will not restore a file with more than one hard link (/etc/resolv.conf) No such file or directory 
kernel: gdm-binary[5833]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fff4188c080 error 4
kernel: gdm-binary[5855]: segfault at 00000000000000d4 rip 0000000000413af2 rsp 00007fff047fa3d0 error 4
```

I'm not sure if the GDM segfault below is related to the avc denial messages.
Any suggestions of where else to look for details? Permissions on certain files/dirs might be incorrect?

Comment: Old question, but the presence of `comm="rhgb"` makes me very suspicious that this might be a hacked system. In RHEL 5.x, `rhgb` is a kernel option, not an executable binary. And I don't see why RedHat Graphical Boot (i.e. the boot splash screen) should mess with `fontconfig` at all. The failure of GDM might be because of an intruder has attempted to install a rootkit that has worked less than perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If SELinix is in permissive mode (as you say, check by running `getenforce(1)`), it will just log accesses it would have denied. So this can't be the cause then. But the system relies ever more on DBus, and that seems to be failing for some reason.

Any third-party packages installed? Check them, uninstall what isn't required, see if there are official alternatives for the others.

There is a strange mention of `/etc/resolv.conf` having several links, check which ones (`find / -xdev -samefile /etc/resolv.conf` will tell you; it could take some time). What does that file contain? Or perhaps it doesn't exist? How is the network configured for this machine?

Check that the system hasn't got damaged packages: `rpm -Va` (this has the tendency to report broken packages even when they are freshly installed, so don't be  too worried; but look over the list).

Update everything: `yum -y update --skip-broken`, check that everything gets updated. If some package can't be updated, find out why and see to fix it.