# After enabling SELinux (permissive mode) on Debian Wheezy, gdm3 does not finish loading

Tags: debian, selinux, gdm3

I recently enabled SELinux on my Debian Wheezy system, in permissive mode (I have confirmed that it is indeed operating in permissive mode). However, after the file labelling double-reboot, gdm3 doesn't seem to start properly. The SELinux setup details are in [What's missing with my SELinux installation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136988/2465) (until there is a proper answer on that question, make sure to also check the comments on the question as they contain vital information).

**Specifically,** gdm3 just sits spinning the doughnut "wait" mouse cursor. I can move the mouse around, but even several minutes (fifteen minutes and counting at the time of this writing), I don't get the login dialog box.

Logging into a text-based shell and issuing `startx` with an old-school ~/.xsession does give me my usual desktop virtually instantly, so it's not a general problem with X, although it did give off a complaint about unable to start something that had to do with notifications. (That might be related simply to running multiple unrelated X client sessions on the same host.)

I checked /var/log/messages and there's a small handful of selinux "denied" entries in there from during the boot, but nothing that seems related to either X or gdm3. I also don't see anything out of the ordinary in /var/log/X* or /var/log/gdm3/*. Considering that I'm running in permissive mode, [SELinux shouldn't be getting in the way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65821/2465).

**How do I figure out what's wrong? How do I fix it?** (I have no particular reason to use gdm3 other than that it's what was enabled by default on Wheezy; if the fix is "use some other display manager", I'm perfectly fine with that, but if so I appreciate specific steps to change that.)

The question [Debian 7 black screen after loading OS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105260/2465) appears to be about a similar issue but indicates there is no mouse cursor either, but it has no answers, no comments, might have nothing at all to do with SELinux (which I feel is likely to be the culprit here, somehow), and hasn't seen any activity for half a year.

Comment: have you filtered your AVC denials through `audit2allow` to see more meaningful messages (`ausearch -m avc -ts recent | audit2allow`)?

Comment: That is not consistent with having "denials" in your logs, please post a sample of your `/var/log/messages`

Comment: @dawud Removing `-ts recent` gives me suggested rules for `apcupsd_t`, `auditd_t`, `cupsd_config_t`, `dhcpc_t`, `fsadm_t`, `getty_t`, `hostname_t`, `ifconfig_t`, `iptables_t`, `loadkeys_t`, `local_login_t`, `mount_t`, `rpcd_t`, `setfiles_t`, `setrans_t`, `udev_t`, `unconfined_t` and `unlabeled_t`. Out of those, it seems like `getty_t`, `hostname_t` and `local_login_t` might reasonably be related. But I still fail to see why this would have much impact with SELinux in permissive mode?

Comment: The `-ts recent` was an example. Use the timeframe you feel is correct (`today`, for example). Indeed, it shouldn't matter there are denials if SELinux is in permissive mode. Sadly, SELinux in Debian is not completely integrated yet, and there are a lot of rough edges.

Comment: @dawud Well, even removing the -ts specifier entirely gives a totally reasonable amount of output.

Comment: I certainly can disable gdm3 entirely and just log in to a shell and use startx, but if there's a graphical solution possible it'd be nice.

Comment: The fact that you can see `unlabeled_t` in your logs is not a good sign. Every file should be correctly labeled. Try relabeling your system and see if it improves WRT the `gdm3` problem.

Comment: When debugging selinux, it is helpful to post the actual denial (log). `ausearch -m avc -ts recent | audit2why` will help, but, from your post, there seem to be a large number of denials and it is not clear if you have to relabel or debug you selinux policy.

Comment: @dawud I tried `sudo fixfiles relabel` and it said `Relabeling / /dev /dev/pts /run /run/lock /run/shm /sys`, a bunch of `*`, and then four times `find: unknown predicate '-context'`. `find` is provided by findutils which is at the latest version. Rebooting replacing `security=selinux selinux=1` with only `selinux=0` allowed gdm3 to load just fine. I'm willing to post some ausearch output, I just don't see anything that appears related. I sort of get the feeling this isn't going to work out for the time being, at least not without a *lot* of fiddling (the rough edges you mentioned earlier)?

Comment: Maybe I'm better off just waiting for Jessie and trying it again at that point?

Comment: If you want stable, you need to wait for jessie to be released. You can try testing, or other distros (Fedora). FWIW, this is one of the main reasons I switched from Debian.

Comment: @dawud The stability is actually one of the reasons I switched *to* Debian (knowing full well it comes with the downside that the software is far from bleeding edge). If you'd be willing to write up a short answer with what's been found out in the comments to this question, I'll very likely accept it; if you don't have the time, say so and I'll write something up myself as an answer summarizing the discussion in the comments. In either case, thank you very much for your help; I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: +1 to the suggestion to use Fedora. If stability is important, RHEL, Centos, or Scientific.

Comment: This seems to be a known bug - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734649

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Note that that bug report specifically talks about switching to "enforcing mode". Even so, good for reference.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Please, provide an answer yourself, I don't feel I've been helpful enough :)